# MediaWiki API, mobileview

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia

I am trying to get a mobile suitable version of the page with the query *http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?mobileformat=&noimages=&format=json&action=parse&prop=text&page=Snow*. I expected that the page content would be like on the mobile version of wikipedia, but I am still receiving the desktop version with wide tables etc. However the result contains no images.

Answer (score 2):

Width is controlled by style sheets which you'll have to add yourself. There are no images because you specified the no images parameter.

Comment: Its not as simple as you think, some tables just have too many columns and information can't fit, also it not the only problem. I am seeking the way of native mobile support in other case I could write a parser myself.